# Extending interfaces using inheritance

Tags: c++

```
class IA
{
public:
    virtual void a() = 0;
};

class A: public IA
{
public:
    virtual void a()
    {
    }
};

class IB
{
public:
    virtual void b() = 0;
};

class B: public IB, public A
{
public:
    virtual void b()
    {
    }
};

void f(IA* p)
{

}

int main() 
{
    B b = B();
    IB* p = &b;
    f(p);
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement interfaces with inheritance in C++? If so, how do I get the line `f(p);` in my code to compile? Basically, I would like if `IB` could inherit from `IA` but this will cause problems for B.

**UPDATE**

What I want is for `IB` to include `IA`'s interface, as follows. However this code wont compile since `IA::a()` and `A::a()` conflict with each other. What should I do?

```
class IA
{
public:
    virtual void a() = 0;
};

class A: public IA
{
public:
    virtual void a()
    {
    }
};

class IB : public IA
{
public:
    virtual void b() = 0;
};

class B: public IB, public A
{
public:
    virtual void b()
    {
    }
};
```

**UPDATE 2**

This compiles, does it look correct? Do I need all these virtuals

```
class IA
{
public:
    virtual void a() = 0;
};

class A: virtual public IA
{
public:
    virtual void a()
    {
    }
};

class IB: virtual public IA
{
public:
    virtual void b() = 0;
};

class B: virtual public IB, public A
{
public:
    virtual void b()
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: `IB` and `IA` are no way related to each other.It is difficult to know what you are trying to do with passing `IB*` where the function expects `IA*`

Comment: Why don't you pass `&b` directly into `f`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is the right way of course, but the line `f(p)` should not compile as is, imagine classes that implement `IB`, but don't implement `IA`, it's possible, so you cannot assume that they all implement `IA`. If you want to assume that, you can inherit `IB` from `IA`, but this is another design. It can be implemented like this:

```
class IA
{
public:
    virtual void a() = 0;
};

class A: virtual public IA
{
public:
    virtual void a()
    {
    }
};

class IB : virtual public IA
{
public:
    virtual void b() = 0;
};

class B: public IB, public A
{
public:
    virtual void b()
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: I can inherit IB form IA - which is exactly the design I want. But what should B then inherit from if it is to implement the IB interface and get A's implementation?

Comment: @Baz, doesn't virtual inheritance from `IA` help?

Comment: Yes! Virtual inheritance is what I'm looking for. Is it good practice to always inherit interfaces as virtual?

Comment: @Baz, this is another question really, would you _always_ inherit all interfaces virtually. I would not probably do this in every case, but when I expect extensions of particular interface by other interfaces, probably. You can start a new question for this.